# Prove that $SC=SP$ if and only if $MK=ML.$

Tags: geometry

> Point $P$  lies inside triangle $ABC$.  Lines $AP$, $BP$, $CP$ meet the circumcircle of $ABC$. again at points $K, L, M,$ respectively. The tangent to the circumcircle at $C$ meets line $AB$ at $S$. Prove that $SC=SP$ if and only if $MK=ML.$

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $CA>CB$, so point $S$ lies on the ray $AB$.

From the similar triangles $△PKM  \sim  △PCA$ and $△PLM \sim △PCB$ we get $\frac{PM}{KM}=\frac{PA}{CA}$ and $\frac{LM}{PM}=\frac{CB}{PB}$.   Multiplying these two equalities, we get $$\frac{LM}{KM}=\frac{CB}{CA}\cdot \frac{PA}{PB}.$$

Hence, the relation $MK=ML$ is equivalent to $\frac{CB}{CA}=\frac{PB}{PA}$

Denote by $E$ the foot of the bisector of angle $B$ in triangle $ABC.$   Recall that the locus of points $X$ for which $\frac{XA}{XB}=\frac{CA}{CB}$ is the Apollonius circle $Ω$ with the center $Q$ on the line $AB$,  and this circle passes through $C$ and $E.$ Hence, we have $MK=ML$ if and only if $P$ lies on $Ω$,  that is $QP=QC.$

[image]

Now we prove that $S=Q$, thus establishing the problem statement. We have  $\angle CES=\angle CAE+\angle ACE+ \angle BCS+ \angle ECB +\angle ECS,$ so $SC=SE.$ Hence, the point $S$ lies on $AB$ as well as on the perpendicular bisector of $CE$ and therefore coincides with $Q.$

**AND WE'RE DONE**

Comment: very nice proof, thnk you very much